# Tag badges seem to be inactive

Tags: bug, badges

The tag badge system seems to be inactive at the moment. No gear icon appears next to the privilege tracker for me on my main user profile (which would be used to switch it to tracking a tag badge), and everyone's meta profile only shows their reputation, not the tag badge tracker. Additionally, it looks like I [should](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/users/75/ben-n?tab=tags) have a bronze [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag here on meta, but no such badge has been awarded.

Meta here (my profile):

[image: meta here]

Meta Super User ([Mokubai](https://meta.superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai?tab=topactivity)'s profile):

[image: meta SU]

This isn't urgent by any stretch of the imagination, and it could conceivably be by design during private betas (though I couldn't find an MSE on it), but I'll file a bug just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), although it is not because of the private beta.

From [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732):

> A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.

Since we don't have tags with 100 questions or more, we don't yet see tag badges.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten about that requirement. Nice find!